# Updating multiple $scope properties in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a method in my controller called `swap()` but for some reason, when I try to switch properties, like making product1 become product2 an product2 become product1, nothing happens. However, if I set product1 as product2 without setting product2 as product1, it works fine. Its just that I can't update multiple scope properties.

```
$scope.swap = function(id) {
        var products = {};
        var old = $scope.products.product1;

        switch(id) {
            case 2:
                products.product2 = old;// Our old one
                products.product1 = $scope.products.product2;
                products.product3 = $scope.products.product3;
            break;
            case 3:
                products.product3 = old;// Our old one
                products.product1 = $scope.products.product3;
                products.product2 = $scope.products.product2;
            break;
        }

        $scope.products = products;
        console.log($scope.products);

    };
```

Could anyone shed some light onto this matter?

Comment: Any chance you could show some before/after examples of what you expect it to look like vs what you're seeing?

Comment: Basically, I'm seeing no actual change in $scope.products. However, lets say I have `swap(2)` basically i want to switch `$scope.products.product1` with `$scope.products.product2`.

Comment: How are you calling `swap()`, as in, what triggers it?

Comment: `<div id="product-2" class="product_container" ng-click="swap(2);"></div>`

It recognizes it as a click event, and it even updates it, but its filling it with the same information.

Comment: Ah, is it in a repeater? You should probably just use an array instead of an object

Comment: @Phil it wasn't, but I think a lingering directive was messing with it. Posted my fix, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I for some reason I fixed this issue by changing this:

`<div class="page-inner" mg-bind-html="products" compilehtml>`
 to this:
`<div class="page-inner">`

Comment: Much easier to help if you show all code. You have resolved this in your markup but only linked the js